# Проблема Sendmail ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

Здравствуйте, установил sendmail в ubuntu 12.04 и провел настройки

1. правильный hostname
2. настройки php.ini: sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
3. resolv.conf: nameserver IP сайта

Шлю письмо:

```
php -r "mail('моя почта', 'Тестовое письмо с вашего сайта', 'Привет. Это тестовое сообщение.')"
```

Получаю лог **/var/log/syslog:**

```
Feb 25 14:51:17 server sendmail[1815]: s1PEpH7C001815: Authentication-Warning: 'мой сайт': www-data set sender to 'почта отправителя' using -f 
Feb 25 14:51:17 server sendmail[1815]: s1PEpH7C001815: from='почта отправителя', size=3515, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<da4ab915f2b2fd79b3ba547c78bb9e4a@'мой сайт'>, relay=www-data@localhost 
Feb 25 14:51:17 server sendmail[1815]: s1PEpH7C001815: to='моя почта', delay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=33515, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
```

и письмо в итоге не доходит. куда копать?

Логи: **/var/log/mail.log:**

```
Feb 25 14:50:40 server sendmail[1797]: s1PEoeBo001797: to='моя почта', delay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=33497, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
Feb 25 14:51:17 server sendmail[1815]: s1PEpH7C001815: Authentication-Warning: 'мой сайт': www-data set sender to 'почта отправителя' using -f
Feb 25 14:51:17 server sendmail[1815]: s1PEpH7C001815: from='почта отправителя', size=3515, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<da4ab915f2b2fd79b3ba547c78bb9e4a@'мой сайт'>, relay=www-data@localhost
```

---

если письма встают только в очередь, то как заставить обрабатывать их по мере поступления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> куда копать?

```
/var/log/mail.log
```

Принимающий сервак может отвергать письмо за многие вещи, например, если адрес не FQDN.

Я в логах не вижу сообщения об отправке или ошибке (только о постановке в очередь). У меня постфикс, и он в логах довольно подробно документирует, что поставлено в очередь, что отправлено, что и по какой причине было заблокировано, почему удаленный сервер отказал в приемке.

Comment: Добавил лог mail.log